# How can I run a command automatically upon connecting to a Bluetooth device?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mouse, bluetooth

**Background**:

I'm using a Bluetooth mouse with my computer. I'm left-handed, and I need to run this command:

```
xinput set-button-map 'RAPOO BT3.0 Mouse' 3 2 1
```

every time it connects, because it resets to default buttons for some reason. I've aliased this command to `left`. Sometimes I have to connect to the mouse manually using `bluetoothctl`, like so:

```
alias mouse="bluetoothctl power on && bluetoothctl connect B4:EE:25:C2:0E:04"
```

In that case, it should be easy enough to add this to the alias:

```
alias mouse="bluetoothctl power on && bluetoothctl connect B4:EE:25:C2:0E:04 && sleep 3 && left"
```

However, sometimes the mouse connects automatically to my computer, and in that case I *also* want to run the `left` command.

**The question**:

Is it possible to run a command automatically every time a specific Bluetooth device connects to the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Make a script with the commands.

Then use:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

to get the `idVendor` and the `idProduct`, then write the udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-my_bluetooth_rule.rules` as follows:

```
ACTION=="add" , SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="yyy", RUN+="/home/myhome/my_script"
```

Run:

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Reconnect your bluetooth device. You can use logger in your bash script to write messages to syslog.

---

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476116/338177)